# Parsing a String That's Kind of JSON

Tags: json, regex

I have a set of strings that's JSONish, but totally JSON uncompliant. It's also kind of CSV, but values themselves sometimes have commas.

The strings look like this:

ATTRIBUTE: Value of this attribute, ATTRIBUTE2: Another value, but this one has a comma in it, ATTRIBUTE3:, another value...

The only two patterns I can see that would mostly work are that the attribute names are in caps and followed by a : and space. After the first attribute, the pattern is , name-in-caps : space.

The data is stored in Redshift, so I was going to see if I can use regex to resolved this, but my regex knowledge is limited - where would I start?

If not, I'll resort to python hacking.

Comment: First of all, ask yourself : _"What I want to retrieve from my input?"_. After, you could search how to do this. A good point, you noticed a "pattern" in your input on which you can write a regex.

Comment: I essentially want to retrieve a clean accessible key/value store that I can analyze, or convert to a columnular data set.
The answer might just be: I need to learn regex.

Comment: I don't mind to help. ;) Which language do you want to use for the regex? You can edit your question to add all info you wrote in your comments.

Comment: Do colons occur in any places other than between `ATTRIBUTE` and `Value`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing would be something like:

```
^([A-Z\d]+?): (.*?), ([A-Z\d]+?): (.*?), ([A-Z\d]+?): (.*)$
```

Though this answer would imply your third attribute value doesn't really start with a comma, and that your attributes name could countain numbers.

If we take this appart:

- `[A-Z\d]` Capital letters and numbers
- `+?:` As many as needed, up to the first `:`
- `(.*?),` a *space*, then as many characters as needed up to a *coma* and a *space*
- `^` and `$` The begining and the end of a string, respectively

And the rest is a repetition of that pattern.

The `( )` are just meant to identify your capture sections, in this case, they don't impact directly the match.

[Here's a working example](https://regex101.com/r/xcQmlN/1)

Comment: Your answer wont work, it will select all the string after the first capitals followed by a colon and a space (i.e. `Value of this attribute, ATTRIBUTE2: Another value, but this one has a comma in it, ATTRIBUTE3:, another value`.

Comment: You're right, though the example given doesn't seem to represent the needs, for there's also numbers, in the example, and the 3rd value starts with a comma... Thie would match better the presence of numbers, the three attributes, but not the comma `[A-Z\d]+?:\s(.*?), [A-Z\d]+?:\s(.*?), [A-Z\d]+?:\s(.*?)`

Comment: Let's wait the OP to clarify its needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Often regex is not the right tool to use when it seems like it is.

Read this thoughtful post for details: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems

When a simpler scheme will do, use it!  Here is one scheme that would successfully parse the structure as long as colons only occur between attributes and values, and not in them:

**Code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string data = "ATTRIBUTE: Value of this attribute,ATTRIBUTE2: Another value, but this one has a comma in it,ATTRIBUTE3:, another value,value1,ATTRIBUTE4:end of file";


    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("As an String");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine(data);

    string[] arr = data.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    Dictionary<string, string> attributeNameToValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("As an Array Split on ':'");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("{\"" + String.Join("\",\"", arr) + "\"}");

    string currentAttribute = null;
    string currentValue = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            // The first element only has the first attribute name
            currentAttribute = arr[i].Trim();
        }
        else if (i == arr.Length - 1)
        {
            // The last element only has the final value
            attributeNameToValue[currentAttribute] = arr[i].Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            int indexOfLastComma = arr[i].LastIndexOf(",");
            currentValue = arr[i].Substring(0, indexOfLastComma).Trim();
            string nextAttribute = arr[i].Substring(indexOfLastComma + 1).Trim();

            attributeNameToValue[currentAttribute] = currentValue;

            currentAttribute = nextAttribute;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("As a Dictionary");
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (string key in attributeNameToValue.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key + " : " + attributeNameToValue[key]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> As an String
>
> ATTRIBUTE: Value of this attribute,ATTRIBUTE2: Another value, but this one has a comma in it,ATTRIBUTE3:, another value,value1,ATTRIBUTE4:end of file
>
> As an Array Split on ':'
>
> {"ATTRIBUTE"," Value of this attribute,ATTRIBUTE2"," Another value, but this one has a comma in it,ATTRIBUTE3",", another value,value1,ATTRIBUTE4","end of file"}
>
> As a Dictionary
>
> ATTRIBUTE : Value of this attribute
>
> ATTRIBUTE2 : Another value, but this one has a comma in it
>
> ATTRIBUTE3 : , another value,value1
>
> ATTRIBUTE4 : end of file